# getting an undefined in html from ajax response

Tags: php, html, ajax

(sorry for misspelled words)
Hi everyone
hope you have a nice time.
I am using ajax for the first time and trying to add some elements (sent and received messages) to html through ajax but only thing i get is an undefined text in html.

messageInsert and first ajax work ok but from get_msg I get an sql syntax error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND incoming_id = ) OR (outgoing_id = AND incoming_id = ) ORDER BY msg_id DESC' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\myProjects\Chatbot\php\get_msg.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\myProjects\Chatbot\php\get_msg.php(9): mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM m...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\myProjects\Chatbot\php\get_msg.php on line 9

messageInsert.php :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'connection.php';
    if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
        $outgoing_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(connection() , $_POST['outgoing_id']);
        $incoming_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(connection() , $_POST['incoming_id']);
        $message = mysqli_real_escape_string(connection() , $_POST['message']);
        if (!empty($message)) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO messages (outgoing_id, incoming_id, msg) VALUES ($outgoing_id , $incoming_id , '$message')";
            $result =connection()->query($query);
        }
    }
```

get_msg.php :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'connection.php';
    if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
        $outgoing_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(connection() , $_POST['outgoing_id']);
        $incoming_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(connection() , $_POST['incoming_id']);
        $output = "";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (outgoing_id = {$outgoing_id} AND incoming_id = {$incoming_id}) OR (outgoing_id = {$incoming_id} AND incoming_id = {$outgoing_id}) ORDER BY msg_id DESC";
        $result = connection()->query($query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if ($outgoing_id === $row['outgoing_id']) {
                $output ='<div class="message-send my-4">
                               <p>'.$row['msg'].'</p>
                           </div>';
            } else {
                $output = '<div class="message-receive">
                                <img class="message-receive-pic mb-3 me-2" src="style/ProfilePic/'.$_SESSION['userPic'].'" alt="">
                                <div class="message-receive-text-box my-4">
                                    <p> '. $row['msg']  .'</p>
                                </div>
                           </div>';
            }
            echo $output;
        }
    }
```

my ajax :

```
let form = document.querySelector(".mySend"),
    sendInput = form.querySelector(".message"),
    sendBtn = form.querySelector(".sendBtn"),
    chatBox = document.querySelector(".chat-box");
form.onsubmit = (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
}
sendBtn.onclick = ()=> {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST" , "http://localhost/project/myProjects/Chatbot/php/messageInsert.php" , true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = ()=> {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200){
                sendInput.value = "";
            }
        }
    }
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
setInterval(()=> {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let data = "";
    xhr.open("POST" , "php/get_msg.php" , true);
    xhr.onload = ()=> {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                data = this.response;
                chatBox.innerHTML = data;
            }
        }
    }
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.send(formData);
}, 500);
```

my html :

```
<div class="chat-box">

    </div>
    <div class="type-box">
        <form class="mySend" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userProfile['id'] ?>" name="incoming_id">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["profileID"] ?>" name="outgoing_id">
            <input class="message form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type your message here..." name="message">
            <button type="submit" class=" sendBtn btn btn-dark" name="sendBtn"><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I am sure about table and columns names.

I appreciate your help so much:)

I have tried everything in ajax and php files , nothing worked.

Comment: There are no quotes around your PHP variables in your SQL query. Apart from that, it's better to use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL-injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). I also cannot see where you POST your AJAX **data**.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware why should there be quotes around them? These look like integer values. The issue is that empty string is received instead of a number.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware first, reflecting on your second point. I still mention my concern about this, so the casual reader will realize that some people are puzzled by the reason of the down-vote. As about your first point: I think the best approach here in terms of fixing the syntax error is to use `intval()` as outlined in my answer as well. Yet, here some deeper issue might be at play as well, because we have these defined as hidden fields in an HTML form initially and the value is likely already missing at that point. Maybe it's about creating a user who has no such values yet.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware or some logic that is not shared in the question computes those values in a wrong manner. So, the solution to the actual question is to use intval, but the op will likely need to explore further on the reasons of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message of

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND incoming_id = ) OR (outgoing_id = AND incoming_id = ) ORDER BY msg_id DESC' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\myProjects\Chatbot\php\get_msg.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\myProjects\Chatbot\php\get_msg.php(9): mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM m...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\myProjects\Chatbot\php\get_msg.php on line 9

clearly points you to the direction that this line is where you are getting into trouble (the error is thrown at the next line where you attempt to execute it):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (outgoing_id = {$outgoing_id} AND incoming_id = {$incoming_id}) OR (outgoing_id = {$incoming_id} AND incoming_id = {$outgoing_id}) ORDER BY msg_id DESC";
```

Look at the query part of your error message carefully:

**AND incoming_id = ) OR (outgoing_id = AND incoming_id = ) ORDER BY msg_id DESC**

You have no values set for `incoming_id` or `outgoing_id`

This is how you attempt to be loading these values:

```
        $outgoing_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(connection() , $_POST['outgoing_id']);
        $incoming_id = mysqli_real_escape_string(connection() , $_POST['incoming_id']);
```

which clearly suggests that you get empty strings as values for them (since `$_POST['outgoing_id']` and `$_POST['incoming_id']` does not throw errors, you have those keys inside your POST request, albeit their values are empty.)

These values are defined in your HTML, namely at

```
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userProfile['id'] ?>" name="incoming_id">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["profileID"] ?>" name="outgoing_id">
```

given the fact that they end up being empty, we know that `$userProfile['id']` and `$_SESSION["profileID"]` are empty. You will need to look into how these are being defined and possibly wrap `intval` around them, like

```
$intOutgoing_id = intval($outgoing_id);
$intIncoming_id = intval($incoming_id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (outgoing_id = {$intOutgoing_id} AND incoming_id = {$intIncoming_id}) OR (outgoing_id = {$intIncoming_id} AND incoming_id = {$intOutgoing_id}) ORDER BY msg_id DESC";
```

so they will be converted to 0 even if they are empty strings, so the behavior will be that if there are invalid values passed for them, then there will be 0 records in the result set rather than a page crash.

EDIT

Constructed this example:

```
    <div class="type-box">
        <form class="mySend" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="hidden" value="3" name="incoming_id">
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="outgoing_id">
            <input class="message form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type your message here..." name="message">
            <button type="submit" class=" sendBtn btn btn-dark" name="sendBtn"><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>
<script>
let form = document.querySelector(".mySend"),
    sendInput = form.querySelector(".message"),
    sendBtn = form.querySelector(".sendBtn"),
    chatBox = document.querySelector(".chat-box");
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let data = "";
xhr.open("POST" , "bar.html" , true);
xhr.onload = ()=> {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            data = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
}
let formData = new FormData(form);
xhr.send(formData);
</script>
```

and it properly passed the parameters in question. Since something prevents your script from doing so, I recommend debugging and logging your code to see the exact issue. At this point it very much seems that your AJAX request should work, it succeeded in my test.

Comment: thank you so much , get_msg actually works now but I still get undefined in html.

Comment: I agree that `intval()` would work in this case, but it is far better to get used to writing prepared statements.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes, PDO is a good approach and in general I recommend its usage to everyone, including Farid.

Comment: @Farid you have some `hidden` fields in your form that form the basis for said two values. Can you right-click on your form, click on inspect element, navigate to these hidden fields in your structure and tell us what their value is inside your HTML?

Comment: @LajosArpad You don't need PDO for prepared statements. [MySQLi can do it too](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks for the clarification. Indeed, there is a long-going debate of what to use: PDO or MySQLi. (https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-vs-mysqli). Probably you already know on which side I am :D

Comment: @LajosArpad actually hidden fields  have values  I want but php couldn't get them because I wasn't using action attribute in my form , i was trying to pass values to php through ajax. I solved it with using $_SESSION.

Comment: @Farid that's a work-around. Let me look into your AJAX, will edit my answer soon.

Comment: @LajosArpad thank you so much for your precious time.

Comment: @Farid happy to help. I have edited my answer. I have conducted experiments based on your code and the parameters ended up being properly sent in the payload. Therefore something happens at your end specifically that prevents this from working like you expected, so I recommend debugging it. You could put a breakpoint (or a `debugger;` line) to the place in your code that is of interest and see what the values are. You can also console.log(`formData.get("incoming_id")` and things like that to see what the value was at a certain point and whether it had a value at all then)

Comment: @LajosArpad thank you for your help It means a lot , when I found the answer I let you know in this post. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Farid happy to help. If you have further questions, please write them here in the comment section. If this answer will turn out to be leading you to the solution, then you might consider accepting it. Do not hesitate to write if you meet  blocker. Good luck!

Comment: @LajosArpad It worked , the only thing i did was to change this.response to xhr.responseText  and it worked , I don't know how ??? :) thank you again for your time.

Comment: @Farid this makes sense. Then the issue was in the handling of the response rather than the sending of the request. I was focusing on the request sending and found it to be working well. Editing my answer, adding your finding to it. Thanks!

Comment: @Farid here's some further material about `responseText` to read for anyone who's interested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText